# view index, sort results export, pivot table python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I created a dataframe, table, from a pivot table in pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'v1':[5,5,6,6,1,5], 'v2':['c','a','b','a','a','b']})
table=pd.pivot_table(df,index=["v2"],values=["v1"],aggfunc=max)
table.sort_values(by='v1', ascending=True)
```

1) I would like to see also in the table the results of v2.

2) In order to sort I used a new line, is that possible to do it direclty in the pd.pivot_table sentence?

3) in real world some tables are too big to see in the console, what's the best way to export results, to better check them, exporting to .csv?

What I see in the console (Ipyhton shell) is this:

```
v2   v1 
c    5
a    6
b    6
```

Comment: I edited the question: I would like to reproduce/export the same results that I see in the console, while in table I see only v1, that is how use v2 as a column instead of index in the pivot to see that kind of results?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `pivoting` the table, a more straight forward alternative is grouped aggregation for your problem; To see `v2` as a normal column instead of index, you can use `reset_index()`; the sort part has to be applied separately but you can chain the `sort_values` directly after other commands, if you prefer one liner; to see a big table in console, usually you can use `.head()` to view a few top rows of your table:

```
df.groupby('v2').max().reset_index().sort_values('v1', ascending=True)

#  v2   v1
#2  c   5
#0  a   6
#1  b   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider resetting index and sorting directly on the `pivot_table()` call:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["v2"],values=["v1"],aggfunc=max).reset_index().sort_values(by='v1', ascending=True)

print(table)
#   v2  v1
# 2  c   5
# 0  a   6
# 1  b   6
```